# Cannot open DataSet in Designer - XSD is Missing

Tags: c#, winforms, xsd, dataset

I have a `DataSet` in my C# Winforms project that I use for sending data to Crystal.  This morning, VS will not allow me to open the `DataSet` in the designer anymore.  It displays the following error message: The item 'ScribbleSoftDataSet' does not exist in the project directory.  It may have been moved, renamed, or deleted.  I have verified that the files are still in the project directory and my solution which makes use of the adapters in the dataset still compiles.  I also tried to exclude the `DataSet` from the solution and then add it back again.  Can anyone suggest another solution?  I really don't want to have to build the dataset again since it has about 35 adapters.  Below is a screenshot of what I see in VS 2008 Pro.

[image]

Comment: Okay, I think I know what is wrong.  For some reason VS deleted my XSD file and corrupted the project file.  I found a recent backup of the XSD for the DataSet and included it in the project after removing all the old files pertaining to the DataSet.  Two Designer files were created because there was still and entry in the project file for the old designer file.  This caused a bunch of compiler errors until I straightened out the project file.

Comment: This is a perfect example of why you should always work with your code in source control.

Comment: Yes, @Jeff I agree.  My project is under source control but, it has unfortunately be longer than normal since it has been committed.  We are a small shop and they did not even have source control until I started working here.  Prior to this project, my only experience was Java and it has been difficult going from projects where there have been a large number of developers to me being the only one on a project.  Many lessons have been learned from this experience.

Comment: Many lessons learned = good for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I know what is wrong. For some reason VS deleted my XSD file and corrupted the project file. I found a recent backup of the XSD for the DataSet and included it in the project after removing all the old files pertaining to the DataSet. Two Designer files were created because there was still and entry in the project file for the old designer file. This caused a bunch of compiler errors until I straightened out the project file